# Android: Including a checkbox feature in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which contains names of people from my `People` class. I want to be able to mark multiple people and then delete marked for example.

I have read many questions and seen answers and I've decided I want to do it the following way for simplicity...

I just select the listItem, click on options menu and I select mark. Then a listener will set a private boolean in the person class, isMarked, to true, and then, to tell the user it is marked, a tick appears next to the listItem.

So the question is, is there a way to make an image appear and disappear in android?

EDIT: I have already implemented the options menu and selecting a person and selecting mark then making his/her `marked` variable true. What I basically need is an indicator to the user that that person is marked.

Comment: Why not use `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"`? I would expect that to take ~10% of the code of what you are trying to do. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/Checklist for a sample app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I looked at this multipleChoice option. The thing is, I dont want multiple items to be selected all the time. Only when I'm marking. And I heard that would be even harder to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is have visual feedback for the item's status, then what you probably need is a custom view layout for the items in the ListView. When the list requests a view for the item ([getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) function) you can show/hide an image to indicate the item's status.

Check the documentation for Adapters, as there are a few other functions related to how this is done. You don't show in the question how you've set up the source of the ListView data.

However, as it seems that what you want to do is to select items and then perform actions on them, you should read on about [contextual action bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html) (see the 'Using the contextual action bar'). Some more info in the [menu's page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB), particularly in the '*Enabling batch contextual actions in a ListView or GridView*' section. Selecting items one by one and using the menu to mark them seems like an non-android'y way of doing things.

Comment: frozenkoi solution works really well control control everything from data perspective and in your getView set backgrounds accordingly. Implement UI behaviour more in adapter rather than setting properties in listview

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is, is there a way to make an image appear and disappear in android?

You need to get a reference to the view you want to show/hide and then use the following: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

For example:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
if (isMarked) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```